# Create vector of member variables from vector of class pointers

Tags: c++

I have a `std::vector` containing pointers to instances of `SomeClass`. This class has (among other things) a member variable with type `SomeOtherClass`. I assume there should be a way (some kind of cast for instance) to efficiently create a new vector containing objects of `SomeOtherClass`.

Currently I use the following:

```
std::vector<SomeClass*>objects = {new SomeClass(),...};
std::vector<SomeOtherClass> memberVars;

for(SomeClass* object : objects){
    memberVars.pushback(object->member);
}
```

(Creating both vectors simultaneously is not an option.)

Edit: Question: Is there a more efficient option to achieve this goal?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have right now?  do you want to be able to modify the `SomeOtherClass` of one of the objects pointer to by `objects` from `memberVars`?

Comment: Could you clarify what the "question" part of you post is?

Comment: there ways you could write it athat are different but your code is what will end up being executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got is the best you can do, if you need another vector. It can be made a bit more C++-like with `std::transform` and an insert iterator, but it's hard to see how that code would be any clearer than your simple loop.

You cannot cast one vector type to another, even if their respective *element* types are related.

You can try to obviate the need for it by iterating over your existing container using filtering functions that stop you having to write `->member` everywhere, but that really depends on what you're trying to do (which we don't know).